# Rcpp forbidden conversion when using any() in an if() statement

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to convert my R function to C++ using Rcpp, but I came around errors that I don't understand quite well.

The following code gives my R function, my (poor) attempt to translate it and some examples of uses at the end (testing that the two function return the same thing...)

My R Code function:

```
intersect_rectangles <- function(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max) {
  rez <- list()
  rez$min <- pmax(x_min, y_min)
  rez$max <- pmin(x_max, y_max)

  if (any(rez$min > rez$max)) {
    return(list(NULL))
  }
  return(rez)
}
```

My attempt to create the same function with *Rcpp*.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List Cpp_intersect_rectangles(NumericVector x_min,NumericVector  
x_max,NumericVector  y_min,NumericVector  y_max) {

  // Create a list :
  NumericVector min = pmax(x_min,y_min);
  NumericVector max = pmin(x_max,y_max);
  List L = List::create(R_NilValue);

  if (! any(min > max)) {
    L = List::create(Named("min") = min , _["max"] = max);
  }
  return(L);
}
```

I receive the following error messages:

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/logical/SingleLogicalResult.h:36:2: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Rcpp::sugar::forbidden_conversion<false>'
        forbidden_conversion<x>{
        ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/logical/SingleLogicalResult.h:74:40: note: in instantiation of template class 'Rcpp::sugar::conversion_to_bool_is_forbidden<false>' requested here
                conversion_to_bool_is_forbidden<!NA> x ;
                                                     ^
file637e53281965.cpp:13:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<true, Rcpp::sugar::Negate_SingleLogicalResult<true, Rcpp::sugar::Any<true, Rcpp::sugar::Comparator<14, Rcpp::sugar::greater<14>, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, PreserveStorage>, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, PreserveStorage> > > > >::operator bool' requested here
    if (! any(min > max))
```

If the *Rcpp* function is implemented correctly, then the following should work:

```
u = rep(0,4)
v = rep(1,4)
w = rep(0.3,4)
x = c(0.8,0.8,3,3)
all.equal(intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,x), Cpp_intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,x))
all.equal(intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,w), Cpp_intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,w))
```

What's wrong with my cpp code?

Comment: Are you aware that intersect is a valid R function? You might try using another name.

Comment: @42- I did, thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the code isn't translating correctly is due to how the `any()` *Rcpp sugar* implementation was created. In particular, we have that:

> The actual return type of `any(X)` is an instance of the 
>     `SingleLogicalResult` template class, but the functions `is_true` 
>     and `is_false` may be used to convert the return value to `bool`.

Per https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/unofficial-rcpp-api-documentation/#any

Therefore, the solution is to add `.is_true()` to the `any()` function call, e.g. `!any(condition).is_true()`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List Cpp_intersect_rectangles(NumericVector x_min, NumericVector x_max,
                              NumericVector y_min, NumericVector y_max) {

    // Create a list :
    NumericVector min = pmax(x_min, y_min);
    NumericVector max = pmin(x_max, y_max);
    List L = List::create(R_NilValue);


    if (! any(min > max).is_true()) {
                      // ^^^^^^^^^ Added
        L = List::create(Named("min") = min , _["max"] = max);
    }
    return(L);
}
```

Then, through testing we get:

```
u = rep(0,4)
v = rep(1,4)
w = rep(0.3,4)
x = c(0.8,0.8,3,3)
all.equal(intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,x), Cpp_intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,x))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,w), Cpp_intersect_rectangles(u,v,w,w))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, and for the link. You made my day